# Doubt in a proof of an exercise in Apostol Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I am trying exercises from the book Apostol Modular Functions and Dirichlet series in number theory and I am struck on proving equality in this exercise of chapter 2 .

> I am adding image of some previous problems also because they contain definations useful in problem 8 .
> But please note that I have doubt only in problem 8 .

Image - [image]

My attempt - Using result that fundamental region is $|\tau|>1$ and $|\tau +\tau^* |<1$ , where $\tau^*$ = conjugate of $\tau$  and defination of reduced form that a reduced form is one whose representative $\tau$ belongs to $R_\Gamma$  I obtained relation $b<|a|$.
and using property of discriminant I obtained $|a|<c$.

> My doubt -> I don't know how to obtain  $b\le c$ in first part and how to obtain $b\le a=c$ in second part.
>
> My attempt in these - when I put $a= b$ in conditions of 1st part I get real part of representative $= -  1/2$  , which is a contradiction to defination of fundamental region.
> In 2 nd part, when try to get something by putting $a=c$, I get $4a^2  > 4  a^2$  which implies $0>0$ .

Can someone please help in proving these Equalities in proof. Inequalities I have proved.

Comment: Everyone Please Note that before 2 nd highlighted comment  .. using property of discriminant I obtained a<c. I don't know why it's not appearling in the problem despite the fact I have typed it and even edited question one after seeing question was not containing this detail. Now question is absolutely complete.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ . In particular it is important to put the **whole** formula between dollar signs, not just individual letters.

Comment: The roots of $az^2+bz+c$ are $\frac{-b}{2a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. Since they assume $d=4ac-b^2>0$ and $a>0$, the root with positive imaginary part is $\tau=\frac{-b}{2a}+i\frac{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}{2a}$. Since $|\tau|>1$, then $\frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a^2}=\frac{c}{a}>1$. Therefore, $c>a$. That the absolute value of its real part is $<1$ tells us that $4\frac{b^2}{4a^2}<1$. Therefore, $b^2<a^2$. So, $|b|<a$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I am asking about how to prove equality in the proof. This, what you wrote have already been throught and mentioned in question by me.

Comment: The computation above comes from the condition of the root being in the interior of $R_\Gamma$. The $a=c$ is not proven, but it is the case when $\tau$ is on the part of the boundary of $R_\Gamma$ that is on the unit circle. This contradicts his definition (on section 2.3) of $R_\Gamma$ being open, but well, maybe in between he switched to [this definition of $R_\Gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain#Fundamental_domain_for_the_modular_group).

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy  by 2nd defination that you have mentioned it can be proved

Comment: Yes, in that case you can have $|\tau|=1$, which gives you $a=c$. The condition that in that case $\tau+\tau^*<0$ gives you the $0\leq b$ and the condition that $\tau+\tau^*<1$ gives $b\leq a$.