# Deducing congruence relations from given congruence relations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am trying problems from Apostol Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory and I could not think about this problem from chapter 2 .

> Problem is – Given integers $a, b, c, d\;$ with $ad-bc \equiv 1  \pmod n$, prove that there always exists integers $\alpha,\beta, \gamma, \delta$ such that $\alpha \equiv a \pmod n$, $\beta \equiv b \pmod n$, $\gamma \equiv c \pmod n$, $\delta \equiv d \pmod n$ with $\alpha \delta-\beta \gamma = 1$ .

I am unable to think how to prove existence of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$  which are equivalent  to $a, b, c, d \bmod n$ respectively. 
Can someone please give hints.

Comment: Please read again my comment on your previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483436/doubt-in-a-proof-of-an-exercise-in-apostol-modular-functions-and-dirichlet-serie

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown I know mathjax, the problem is my browser doesn't have preview post option, so I can't see what could be possible mistake.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown  so, I have to edit posts after posting question. I have edited it.

Comment: You are still putting individual symbols between dollar signs rather than the whole formula; not only does that look awful, it's more work than doing it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\overbrace{a\!+\!\ell n}^{\textstyle \alpha},\:\!b)=1\,$ for $\,\ell\in\Bbb Z\,$ by $\,{(a,b,n)=1,}\,$ by [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647665/242) Let $\,\beta =b.\,$ We solve for $\,\delta,\gamma\in\Bbb Z$.

$\!\!\bmod n\!:\ \color{#0a0}{\alpha\equiv a}\,\Rightarrow \color{#0a0}\alpha d\!-\!b c = \color{#0a0}ad\!-\!bc = 1,\ $ so $\,\alpha d\! -\! b c = \color{#c00}{1\!-\!kn}\,$ for $\,k\in\Bbb Z,\,$ hence

$1\! =\! \underbrace{\alpha(d\!+\!in)\!-\!b(c\!+\!jn)}_{\textstyle \alpha\,\delta \,-\, \beta\,\gamma}\! =\! \color{#c00}{1\!-\!kn}\!+\!(i\alpha\!-\!jb)n\!\iff\! i\alpha\!-\!jb = k.\,$ Such $\,i,j\,$ exist by $(\alpha,b)\!=\!1$

Comment: where did you used the hyperlink 'here'. Also, can you please tell as (a, b) =1  but why integers have the form d+in, c+jn in 1= a(d+in) -b ( c+jn) ?

Comment: can you please  elaborate your answer, I am sorry but i am confused.

Comment: @user686624 I expanded it. Note  $\,\delta \equiv d\pmod{\!n}\,$  $\Rightarrow\,\delta = d + in\,$ for $\, i\in \Bbb Z,\,$ and similarly $\,\gamma\equiv c\pmod{\!n}\,$ $\Rightarrow\, \gamma = c + jn\,$ for $\,j\in\Bbb Z.\,$ Above we show that such $\,i,j\,$ exist satisfying $\,\alpha  \delta - \beta \gamma = 1\ \ $

Comment: which result are you using to prove existence of such i, j?   gcd of $\alpha$ , b is 1 but k not necessarily equal to 1?

Comment: @user686624 The well-known [basic result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/662686/242) that $\,\exists\, x,y\in\Bbb Z\!:\ ax+by=c\iff (a,b)\mid c\ $ or, equivalently, $\,\exists\, x\!:\ ax\equiv c\pmod{\!b}\iff (a,b)\mid c\ \ \ $

Comment: got it. Can you please look at the problem ( that I have mentioned in this question by editing) . It is related to the problem whose solution ( you have wrote.

Comment: @user686624 If you have another question you need to post it separately (and link to this if it is related).

Comment: Ok  I will do that