# Proving a congruence relation for elements of modular group.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am trying exercises of Tom M Apostol modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory and I am struck on this problem of Chapter 2 .

> Problem is - If (m, n) =1 and A $\epsilon $  $\Gamma$ , then prove that there exists A' in $\Gamma$  such that A'$\equiv$ A ( mod n) and A' $\equiv $ I ( mod m) . 
>   NOTE I is identity matrix here.

This problem visit related to this problem whose link I am giving  -->

[Deducing congruence relations from given congruence relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483645/deducing-congruence-relations-from-given-congruence-relations)

Using above mentioned problem it becomes clear that such a choice of A' is possible. In fact, it is same as given in the answer of Bill Dubuque. But how to prove that A' $\equiv $ I ( mod m) . For this, I must show that b= qm for some q from integers and  other required conditions.

Can somebody please explain how to find such entries in A'
 such that A'$\equiv $I ( mod m) .

Comment: What is $\Gamma$?  and is $I\equiv1\pmod m$?

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner yes I know Chinese reminder theorem

Comment: @J. W. Tanner $\Gamma$ is modular group . I is Identity matrix here.

Comment: Once you know that $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\to SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z})$ is surjective then take $N=nm$ and $SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z})\cong SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})\times SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z})$

Comment: @reuns thank you very much.